# In an adversarial PyTorch model, how to avoid a second forward pass?

Tags: performance, pytorch, backpropagation, generative-adversarial-network

The classic PyTorch example/tutorial for a GAN training loop is shown [here](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html#training).
You can find the lines

```py
# Since we just updated D, perform another forward pass of all-fake batch through D
output = netD(fake).view(-1)
```

but since such an adversary can become quite large this seems like a very unnecessary thing to do. To get more concrete I have a minimal example of my (in some point different) adversarial training where it matters even more (see end of this post). Basically, I have a network `X` that produces output `out1` and a network `Y` that produces two loss terms `out2_x` and `out2_y`. Each of these loss terms should be used to update the weights of the corresponding model. So to update the weights of `X` I need to do a full backward pass through both networks. If I count the runtime costs in terms of network evaluations (forward or backward) I have now had 2 forward and 2 backward network evaluations. To update the second network, I hoped just to clear the previous gradients of this part and do a backward pass till `out1` and stop there. This would add one additional backward network evaluation and I have all my needed gradient updates.

The aforementioned GAN tutorial would suggest doing an additional forward pass on the second network which would result in a total of 6 instead of 5 network evaluations, which seems to me like easily avoidable and unnecessary.

However my idea of stoping somehow autograds backward pass early seems not easily possible. I found a solution that behaves like described above (see example below), but I wonder if it isn't to expensive, as setting `require_grads` to False for all `X` weights means that PyTorch also needs to do some additional graph updates to figure out how deep the backward pass needs to go, and as this happens on the Python side (right?) this can be potentially quite slow for large network architectures with many single tensor operations?! Also with having one single bottleneck tensor `out1` I was hoping to have a cleaner code by telling autograd specifically to stop the backward pass there, and now I am really curious why this seems so hard to achieve in the framework.

Any insights are very much appreciated!

```py
import torch

# Setting up a dummy graph
x1: torch.Tensor = torch.tensor(1.0, requires_grad=True)
x2: torch.Tensor = torch.tensor(3.0, requires_grad=True)

out1 = x1 * (x2 + 1)
y: torch.Tensor = torch.tensor(11.0, requires_grad=True)

out2_x = out1 * y + y ** 2
out2_y = out1 ** 2 * y ** 2

opt1 = torch.optim.SGD([x1, x2], lr=0.01)
opt2 = torch.optim.SGD([y], lr=0.01)
# Finished setting up a dummy graph

# showcasing some gradients
opt1.zero_grad()
opt2.zero_grad()
out2_x.backward(retain_graph=True)
print("grads wrt out2_x\t\t\t:", x1.grad, x2.grad, y.grad)
opt1.zero_grad()
opt2.zero_grad()
out2_y.backward(retain_graph=True)
print("grads wrt out2_y\t\t\t:", x1.grad, x2.grad, y.grad)

# actual logic for computing gradients
opt1.zero_grad()
opt2.zero_grad()
out2_x.backward(retain_graph=True)
# the following two lines work
x1.requires_grad = False
x2.requires_grad = False
# but I was hoping something like the following would work
#   * out1.requires_grad = False
#   * out1.is_leaf = True
#   * out1.detach() (this would require a second forward pass)
#   * out2_y.backward(tell it to stop at out1)
print("grads wrt out2_x\t\t\t:", x1.grad, x2.grad, y.grad)
opt2.zero_grad()
print("grads after zeroing y\t\t\t:", x1.grad, x2.grad, y.grad)
out2_y.backward()
print("grads after out2_y with no_grads x\t:", x1.grad, x2.grad, y.grad)
opt1.step()
opt2.step()
# x1.requires_grad = True
# x2.requires_grad = True
```

Output:

```
grads wrt out2_x            : tensor(44.) tensor(11.) tensor(26.)
grads wrt out2_y            : tensor(3872.) tensor(968.) tensor(352.)
grads wrt out2_x            : tensor(44.) tensor(11.) tensor(26.)
grads after zeroing y           : tensor(44.) tensor(11.) tensor(0.)
grads after out2_y with no_grads x  : tensor(44.) tensor(11.) tensor(352.)
```